# Dart, constructor with named parameters not working. Positional parameters expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I am reading a book and I wrote the code exactly as instructed.

```
 class Contato extends StatelessWidget{

  final String nome;
  final int idade;

  Contato(this.nome, this.idade){

  }

  Widget build(BuildContext buildContext){
    return Text('sou $nome minha idade e´ $idade');
  }

}
```

I create an instance of this class as this:

```
  new Contato(nome: 'Monica Alves', idade: 32)
```

The above code gives me, two positional parameters expected, 0 found.

Comment: `Contato({this.nome, this.idade})`

Comment: when you create instance remove parameter names. `new Contato('Monica Alves', 32)`

The above solution is right too.

Comment: Yes, @pskink I didn't see the curly braces. What you guys expected I've started learning Flutter/Dart just yesterday.

Comment: *"I've started learning Flutter/Dart just yesterday."* - start from this: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify names for parameters use this

```
 class Contato extends StatelessWidget{

  final String nome;
  final int idade;

  Contato({this.nome, this.idade}){

  }

  Widget build(BuildContext buildContext){
    return Text('sou $nome minha idade e´ $idade');
  }

}
```

Then

```
new Contato(nome: 'Monica Alves', idade: 32)
```

If you don't want the named parameters use this

```
class Contato extends StatelessWidget{

  final String nome;
  final int idade;

  Contato(this.nome, this.idade){

  }

  Widget build(BuildContext buildContext){
    return Text('sou $nome minha idade e´ $idade');
  }

}
```

Then this

```
  new Contato('Monica Alves', 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your class like this:

```
 class Contato extends StatelessWidget{

  final String nome;
  final int idade;

  Contato({ this.nome, this.idade });

  Widget build(BuildContext buildContext){
    return Text('sou $nome minha idade e´ $idade');
  }
}
```

**OR**

you can create an object from class like this one:

```
new Contato('Monica Alves', 32)
```

> `new` keyword is optional.